# Where did my machines take IPv6 addresses?

Tags: networking, ipv6

In `IPv4` I am required to have DHCP server or manual config to assign NIC some address.

In `IPv6` I found that many machines have some addresses despite the fact I never configured them (moreover, I would like to disable `IPv6`, but it is resurrecting like a very sticky virus).

This concerns both Windows and Linux.

So, where did they take their addresses?

**UPDATE**

Addresses are started from `fe80::`, which is [described as "local" in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses). But I am able to ping this local address of one machine from another one.

Comment: IPv6 works very differently than IPv4. What have you learned about IPv6 already? Otherwise we might skip some basic info that we assume you know.

Comment: [What makes you think its any different?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6)

Comment: Nothing. Please don't explain everything, just answer where they took addresses, I would like to learn in my way :)

Comment: @Ramhound it can't be DHCP, because it is not configured.

Comment: @Dims - Most home routers if assigned a IPv6 will also assigned IPv6 addresses.  Why are you trying to disable IPv6 instead of IPv4?  Honestly you have provide no helpful information, you have not even told us, the model of the device handing out IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @Ramhound IPv6 adresses will be automatically generated by the OS if no DHCPv6 is present. That is my point regarding making things differently. I guess this also applies for IPv4 giving you a 169.254.x.x address

Comment: @Ramhound I have separate Unix machine for router. DHCP is not leasing IPv6 addresses there. So, where did my machines took that addresses? I don't like IPv6 because it have very long addresses, I don't need them for local network.

Comment: @LPChip - You sure about that?  I am pretty sure that my home PC isn't assigned a IPv6 address, since I don't believe my provider is not handing them out currently, my router doesn't hand my devices out.

Comment: @Dims, you do know that you can have both IPv6 and IPv4 work concurrently, right? No need to disable ipv6, and if I'm not mistaken, linux has switches for specifically using ipv4 over ipv6 and visa versa.

Comment: @Dims - You are going to need to get more specific.  I don't feel I can generate an answer based on what you have provided.  Specific information on operating systems, network devices, the whole shebang at the minimum.

Comment: @Ramhound if you can't then don't :)

Comment: @Ramhound A LAN is a / 64 address; the first 64 bits of the network address are the same for all nodes in the local network. The last 64 bits make every node on the local network unique. This allows the distribution of IP numbers is superfluous; if use is made of autoconfiguration by the systems connected to the network the last 64 bits are automatically selected itself. Network administrators who find desirable to disable auto-configuration and the addresses manually or handing example through DHCPv6 - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3315

Comment: I don't find questions, I can't answer because they lack information I need to answer them, not to be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound what information do you need? I said I have no `IPv6` `DHCP`. What else you like to know?

Comment: @Dims read this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3315 its the RFC about DCHPv6 implementation, explaining why it gives out an IP address even with no DHCP server present.

Comment: @LPChip - I know all of that.  In my experience the router firmware I use does not assign an IPv6 address unless the device is assigned a IPv6 address.  I might be mistaken though its been awhile since I even looked at what address DCHP device hands out since I know the addresses by heart.

Comment: @Dims - I literally told you what information I need, in my comment, and I quote "specific information on operating systems, network devices, the whole shebang at the minimum.".  You indicate you have a Unix machine serving as a router.  So what is handing out IPv4 addresses, if its not a DHCP server, that means your assigning static addresses?

Comment: @Ramhound I have pfSense, and it has explicitly IPv6 disables. DHCP ranges are set only for IPv4

Comment: @Dims - You have to disable IPv6 on each client.  Your current answer explains what actually is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration_.28SLAAC.29) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration) is the information you're looking for.

It's called Stateless Address Autoconfiguration (SLAAC).  Basically IPv6 (unlike IPv4) has autoconfiguration protocols in the absence of a DHCP server built into its design.

In IPv4, if a network adapter is configured for DHCP but no DHCP server responds, it will auto-assign itself an address of 169.254.x.x(/16).  This is called a link-local address.  Any computer using a link-local address can communicate with other computers using link-local addresses if they are on the same network segment.  The key here is that link-local addressing is not a part of the IPv4 spec; it's a *de-facto* standard popularized by Microsoft.

For IPv6 networks, in addition to the link-local address, you also have SLAAC. In a routed IPv6 infrastructure, routers can supply clients with network info via ICMP the way a DHCP server normally would.  And since IPv6 has these protocols built into the spec, any IPv6 router would support these requests from clients if configured to do so.

Also, the IPv6 address space is so incredibly big that clients can randomly assign themselves addresses with little risk of collision with other hosts.

In this way, an entire IPv6 infrastructure could conceivably auto-configure itself entirely without any kind of IP address management system.

Answer (score 1):

The address start with fe80:: is link-local address .if your system is ipv6 enabled,system will automatically generate this address. It's called Stateless Address Autoconfiguration (SLAAC).For this we dont need any DHCP server.This address Scope is only with in the particular subnet..you cant not access that address from any other subnet.System automatically generating this address from system MAC address.YOU can check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ipv6/ipv6_address_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

The `fe80::` addresses are link-local addresses. Every system automatically configures those on all its interfaces. They are assigned by the system to itself. You can't use them beyond the local link (network, vlan etc) as they are non-routable.

Answer (score 0):

> In IPv4 I am required to have DHCP server or manual config to assign
> NIC some address.

Almost correct. You either ask for on from a server on the network (DHCP), or statically assign a fixed IP, or run some software which generates an IP in an other way when neither of these are used (e.g. the [169.x.x.x addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) sometimes generates when you do not assign an IP and when a DHCP server is not reachable).

Now IP v6 is more modern, this is not an afterthough, link local communication is build into the protocol from the start. This is different from IPv4. Arguably it is better *as long as you are aware of it*.

Now to the reason why I am typing an answer while there are already several:

Yes, `The fe80::` addresses are local. But not local as in the 127/8 range in IP4. That was local **host**. There are **link** local. They are reachable from your local network. It is a minor difference in the text, but quite relevant.